# What is "% accept rate"?

Tags: support, reputation, accepting

The title really says it all...how is this number computed?

Answer (score 5):

The reason and implementation for the "Accept Rate" is covered in this blog post:

[**New Question Asker Features**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)

> In order to increase engagement between the people asking questions and the rest of the community, we’ve rolled out two new features.
>
> The first is a “batting average”, if you will.
>
> Below the question owner signature block, for non-community-wiki questions, we show the percent of accepted answers for that user. It won’t always appear, though. The following rules are used in the calculation:
>
> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - Questions must have at least 1 answer.
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.